# Can we change x to y like that in limit?

Tags: limits, analysis

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\lim _{y\to 0}\left(\cos\left(y\right)\right),\:y\:=\:\frac{1}{x}$
Can I rewrite the limit like so?

Comment: Take care to note which side the limit is approaching from.

Comment: What if it's not a one-sided limit?

Comment: What if *what* is not a one-sided limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although if $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ then $\lim x\to\infty$ would mean that $y=\dfrac{1}{\infty}=0^{+}$ so that

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\lim _{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\cos\left(y\right)\right)$$

In this problem the limit from the right equals the limit from the left

$$\lim _{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\cos\left(y\right)\right)=1=\lim _{y\to 0^{-}}\left(\cos\left(y\right)\right)$$

In general, this isn't always true. Therefore, you should rewrite $\lim _{y\to 0}$ with $\lim _{y\to 0^{+}}.$

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You can because the $x$ are numbers that tend to infinity in an arbitrary way, and the numbers $\dfrac1y$ are also numbers that tend to infinity in an arbitrary way. But make sure that $y$ tends to $0^+$, not $0$.